# how to add __FUNCTION__ into syslog

Tags: c, variadic-functions, syslog

I found the following code can add log into syslog. But if i also want to add `__FUNCTION__` info to the syslog, how to do it?

```
openlog(basename(argv[0]), LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_DAEMON);

int logger(int priority, const char *format, ...) {
int result = 0;
va_list args;

va_start(args, format);

vsyslog(priority, format, args);
vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
va_end(args);

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

First, modify logger to accept the function name:

```
int logger_internal(const char* func, int priority, const char* format, ...);
```

But call it through the macro:

```
#define logger(priority, format, ...) \
  logger_internal(__FUNCTION__, priority, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Modifying the body of `logger_internal` to take the extra parameter into account is a bit annoying, but not difficult.  Probably the most straightforward way would be to prepend the function to the format argument; so something like (untested):

```
int logger_internal(const char* func, int priority, const char* format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  size_t func_l = strlen(func);
  size_t format_l = strlen(format);

  char* fmt = malloc(func_l + format_l + 2);

  memcpy(fmt, func, func_l);
  fmt[func_l] = ' ';
  memcpy(&(fmt[func_l + 1]), format, format_l);
  fmt[func_l + 1 + format_l] = '\0';

  va_start(args, format);
  vsyslog(priority, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  free(fmt);
}
```

But obviously that part would depend on what you wanted your syslog entry to look like.